# PMD support for kotlin

Tags: kotlin, pmd

When IntelliJ PMD plugin asked to check for PMD rules violation, it says

PMDException: Error while parsing RData.kt

Does PMD support kotlin files parsing, if yes, from which version it supports, I have observed the failure in 6.21.0 version.

Comment: PMD does support Kotlin, but this may be an issue with the IntelliJ plugin. PMD has a modular design, where each language support is shipped independently. If the IntelliJ plugin doesn't ship it, it won't be able to analyze it.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/419), PMD support will be added in version 7. Until then, only CPD support is available.